# What is $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow (0,0,0)} \frac{x^{2}+y^3+z^2}{x^{3}+y^{2}+z^2}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do you evaluate $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow (0,0,0)} \frac{x^{2}+y^3+z^2}{x^{3}+y^{2}+z^2}$$

Normally in this situation I would convert this to polar form and replace all the x's with $rcos(\theta)$ and the y's with $rsin(\theta)$

But I have no clue how to get rid of the z's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be given by

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2+y^3+z^2}{x^3+y^2+z^2}$$

If the limit $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$ is approached along the parametric curve given by $x=t$, $y=kt$, and $z=0$ for $t\to 0$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}f(x,y,z)&=\lim_{t\to 0}f(t,kt,0)\\\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1+k^3t}{t+k^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k^2}
\end{align}$$

> Inasmuch as $k$ is arbitrary, the limit of interest fails to exist.